# NSG flow logging and accessing

Tags: azure, azure-nsg

As I researched, Azure NSG flow logs can be stored in three different places. Below I have listed the those destinations and related access methods to them.

**Destination    -->        Access Method**

Storage Account     -->  by portal/ by powershell/ by api

Streamed to Event-hub   -->  by third party tools(eg. Power BI, Elastic Stack)

Log Analytics       -->  ---

And I came across Network Watcher also.

I need to know how to access these Log Analytics, whether I can use an API and where the Network watcher fits in to this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you setup flow logs, you also can enable Trafic Analytics, which sends the data to Log Analytics. Just go to Network Watcher---Traffic Analytics. You can click on any of the charts in this dashboard, and it will take you to Log Analytics and display the appropriate query that generated them. Click the `see all` or `see more` like the screenshot below.

[image]

For more information, you could get this nice [blog](https://samcogan.com/troubleshoot_nsg_issues_network_watcher/).